# why dbreport mediator gets an exception if userTransction is true

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

When I use dbreport mediator using transaction, it went wrong which says:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper cannot be cast to javax.sql.PooledConnection
```

but if i don't the property of useTransaction of dbreport mediator is false, it works fine, I don't konw why this happens, maybe a bug?

below is my configuration:

```
<api context="/transaction" name="TransactionAPI" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<resource methods="GET">
    <inSequence>
        <transaction action="use-existing-or-new"/>
        <dbreport useTransaction="true">
            <connection>
                <pool>
                    <password>1</password>
                    <driver>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver>
                    <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.90.241:1522:orcl</url>
                    <user>bap_sr</user>
                </pool>
            </connection>
            <statement>
                <sql><![CDATA[insert into action_view values('c','s','a')]]></sql>
            </statement>
        </dbreport>
        <send>
            <endpoint key="FormEp"/>
        </send>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
        <transaction action="commit"/>
        <send/>
    </outSequence>
    <faultSequence/>
</resource>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/issues/1176.
You can define the datasource in the master-datasource.xml.